# How can I prove the triangle inequality and the given corollaries?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, mathematical-physics, education, absolute-value, number-systems

How can I prove the following 3 claims? Or, if possible, could you provide suggestions for how I could prove them?

For real numbers $x$ and $y$:

- Claim 1. $|x| − |y| ≤ |x − y|$
- Claim 2. $|x-y| ≤ |x|+|y|$
- Claim 3. $|x| − |y| ≤ |x + y|$

Comment: Welcome to stakexchange. Try the  cases depending on the signs of $x$ and $y$ and the signs of the various sums and differences. (There are faster ways, but you will learn a lot this way.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you made a search here on MSE. I'm pretty sure that your questions are duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to prove the second one (which is called **the triangle inequality**) because the remaining inequalities follows immediately.

Indeed,

1. Let's show that $|x|-|y|\leq |x-y|$. Using the triangle inequality we have, $$|x|=|(x-y)+y|\leq |x-y|+|y|.$$
2. Let's show that $|x|-|y|\leq |x+y|$. Using the triangle inequality we have, $$|x|=|(x+y)+(-y)|\leq |x+y|+|-y|=|x+y|+|y|.$$

In both of them I've used that $|a-b|\leq |a|+|b|$. So it suffices to prove the second one.

Comment: For the second problem it is also an immediate consequence of your first calculation by adding $-\vert y \vert$ to both sides and extracting the appropriate inequality.